# Change the primary tag for certain Google renamed services?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Google has renamed some services in the last few months. While we have managed to add the correct tag synonyms to those services, there still appear under their old name on the posts. Here is a list of services, feel free to extend:

- Google Market *now* Google Play Store
- Google Places *now* Google+ Local (has now tag atm)

I think this should be changed, so that the official name appears as tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and merged the older tags with their newer rebranded versions. Just to record exactly what was changed, I merged and synonymized the following:

- [market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market) is now [google-play-store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store)
- [google-places](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-places) is now [google-plus-local](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-local)
- [google-books](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-books) is now [google-play-books](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-books)
- [google-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-music) is now [google-play-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-music)
- <s>[google-docs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) is now [google-drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)</s> (reverted due to [this reason](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2584))

If you see a tag that was missed then feel free to leave a comment on this answer and I'll get to it when I have a chance.

Answer (score 7):

Now that the changes have been live for a while I would tend to agree. The old tag should be a synonym for the new and the tag wiki should very obviously state that the thing wasn't always named that.

> Up until April 2012, the Google Play Store was known as the Android Market and was changed as part of Google's initiative to consolidate their marketplace for Android apps, music, movies, and books.

Comment: My only thought on this would be whether or not we should be worried about not having a `market` tag for old/un-updated devices, although I don't even know if that would be truly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In 2012, there was only Google Drive app for editing Documents, Slides, and Presentations.

On June 2014, Google released standalone editor apps for each file: Google Docs, Google Sheets, and Google Slides. (Ref: [Google Drive Blog](http://googledrive.blogspot.sg/2014/06/newdocssheetsslides.html))

> #### Mobile apps for Docs, Sheets and now Slides
>
> We recently launched mobile apps for Docs and Sheets that allow you to create and edit files on the go, even if you’re offline. We’re rounding out the trio with a new Slides mobile app that’s available starting today on Android and in the coming weeks on iOS.

Thus, the current synonymization of [google-docs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) to [google-drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) can be considered confusing and degrading the user experience.

With this:

- [google-drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) is now mainly for managing Google's cloud storage
- [google-docs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) has been un-synonymized from [google-drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive), recreated and added to a few questions
- [google-sheets](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) already exists
- [google-slides](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-slides) will be created when needed