# Should we have google-music and google-play-music tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

While writing [this suggested edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1597) I wondered if we should create two tags:

- [google-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-music)
  For questions about the App
- [google-play-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-music) For questions about the Google's Play Music store/service

**or**

should we handle both type of questions within the same tag and create a new synonym [google-play-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-music) for [google-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-music). Since sometimes questions will be related to both topics.

Comment: I'm a little on the fence about this. My inclination is actually to retag everything with `google-play-music` since there is no longer a service or app named `google-music`. The app *does* identify itself as "Play Music" on your device, so tagging it with something else could be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is part-and-parcel of [Change the primary tag for certain Google renamed services?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/change-the-primary-tag-for-certain-google-renamed-services) I suppose this question is probably a duplicate.

The app  recently had its name changed to **Google Play Music**, so I think the tag for that should be [google-play-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-music). The store/service is really [google-play-store-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store-music) but do we really want questions tagged with that? [google-play-store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store) seems like it should suffice.

Comment: Moreover, having a tag dedicated to a service (while retaining a separate tag for the related app) might cause confusion with what's clearly defined as being off-topic (here: independent questions concerning services -- at least at a first glance that's how I'd understand this, thinking the service itself might be available independent from Android, which I might be wrong with).